# How do I fix this error, what does it mean Category has no attribute 'get_impath'?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I wrote tests for my model, but there is an error. I cannot fix that.

The error message `AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'get_impath'`

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import *


class CategoryTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Category.objects.create(name='Python', impath='img.png')

    def test_category_models(self):
        category_test = Category.objects.get(name='Python')
        self.assertEqual(
            category_test.get_impath(), "img.png")
```

Here is my model

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    impath = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add the `Category` model.

Comment: Note that the error in your question is different than the error in your title. Please show the definition of your `Category` model.

Comment: it means exactly what it says, you haven't defined a `get_impath()` method on your Category model.

Comment: ```from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 impath = models.CharField(max_length=64)
``` Here is my medel for Category

Comment: @АйсулуАбдраимова, please include this code in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
Category.objects.create(name='Python', impath='img.png')
```

I assume this means you have something like

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    impath = models.ImageField()
```

Here `impath` is an attribute. Django does not automatically create a method named `get_impath()`. This means you need to do `category_test.impath` instead of `category_test.get_impath()`. Fields in your model are attributes and there are no `get` methods for them unless you write them yourself.

Note that you are writing a test that verifies that Django works the way the documentation says it will. This is good for learning about how Django works and how to write tests in the Django environment. However, beyond that, such tests are not worth very much because you should assume that the authors of Django have already tested it.

Comment: oh Thank you so much! Do you know any tutorials for testing Django? Please, can share with me? Thanks!

Comment: @АйсулуАбдраимова Yes, the tutorial in the official Django tutorial contains a section on testing. I suggest you work through the entire thing in order to understand the correct way of using models and writing views.

Comment: @АйсулуАбдраимова Note that if you intend on using `impath` to access a file, you should use `FileField` or `ImageField` instead of `CharField`.